# Javascript Like "Promise.all" on Java 8 (maybe with lambdas)

Tags: javascript, java, android, callback, promise

I would like to know if there is something similar to the "Promise.all" of JavaScript for Java 8 (currently on Android). I am trying to make when all the callbacks finish, then execute a second process.

Now the callbacks that I am using are *lambdas* expressions, but I'm open to suggestions to change the way to do the callbacks and the "big callback" that is executed when all callbacks finishes.

I made it with a counter of callbacks, that when that counter of callbacks is equal to the length of callbacks then call to the big callback. But I am sure that this solution is not the correct one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Java 8 offers this as [CompletableFuture.allOf(CompletableFuture...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#allOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-), which mimics [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all); there is also [CompletableFuture.anyOf(CompletableFuture...)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#anyOf-java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture...-) to mimic [Promise.race](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/race) in Javascript.

If you use ListenableFuture instead, Guava does this as [Futures.allAsList(...)](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/Futures.html#allAsList-com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture...-), with both varargs and iterable overloads.

Comment: Note that unlike `Promise.all()`, `allOf()` does not return array of results - you'll need to keep references to the original Future objects and call `get()` on each of them after invoking the `allOf(...).get()` statement.